# Hibernate joining 2 rows

Tags: hibernate, join, self, discriminator, composite-id

In order to make my java code easier, I would like to join two rows into one since I really need those two to be present in order to use the data.

Let's say those are the fields of my table :

```
ID, FIELD1, FIELD2, DISCRIMINATOR, VALUE
```

Obviously, ID is the primary key.
FIELD1 and 2 let us identify a "group" of 2 rows which only differ by DISCRIMINATOR and VALUE (the discriminator indicate what the value represents)

And I would like to have one POJO per "group" (where FIELD1 and 2 would be used as composite id), like :

```
FIELD1, FIELD2, VALUE1, VALUE2
```

Where :

VALUE1 = VALUE for discriminator A

VALUE2 = VALUE for discriminator B

In SQL, I would request it like this :

```
SELECT a.FIELD1, a.FIELD2, a.VALUE as VALUE1, b.VALUE as VALUE2
FROM TABLE a, TABLE b
WHERE a.FIELD1 = b.FIELD1 and a.FIELD2 = b.FIELD2
  AND a.DISCRIMINATOR = 'A'
  AND b.DISCRIMINATOR = 'B'
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to make it in hibernate, and I'm now confused with all the possibilities.

I'd rather have the solution as mapped XML, but would still take the annotation solution if there's no choice.

Comment: You're thinking in terms of tables.  Hibernate is an ORM solution that lets you pretend that objects are the center of the universe.  You should either think in terms of objects or drop Hibernate for a SQL-based solution like Spring JdbcTemplate or iBatis.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, the application has already a lot a processing made with hibernate, I have no control over the choice made for the db nor the api. I will keep that in mind for future works though.

Comment: It need not be an all or none solution.  You don't have to force Hibernate to do it all.  Why couldn't straight SQL work here?

Comment: I misunderstood your comment, and I think I will try using it since the application is already using the spring framework. Thanks

Comment: That sounds better to me - SimpleJdbcTemplate and a mapping will work just fine.  Let Spring do it.

Comment: The only problem with `SimpleJdbcTemplate` is that the query will not use the Hibernate connection configuration, which may cause it to be executed in a different transaction if you're using something like `JpaTransactionManager`.  If you're using a proper XA transaction manager, or don't really care about transactions for this, then I agree that that's a fine approach.

Comment: Indeed, I use the same datasource bean used by hibernate sessionFactory, but I can't use it's transaction.  
Luckily I don't need to use it in my context.

Comment: Create a data source and give it to both Spring and Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

If you map the table very simply to a POJO (here using annotations, but you could use XML):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "whatever")
public class Fields {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "FIELD1")
    private String field1;

    @Column(name = "FIELD2")
    private String field2;

    @Column(name = "DISCRIMINATOR")
    private String discriminator;

    @Column(name = "VALUE")
    private String value;
}
```

You could define a separate POJO that contained both fields and values:

```
public class FieldValues {
    private String field1, field2, value1, value2;

    public FieldValues( String field1, String field2, String value1, String value2 ) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }
}
```

Then you could use JPQL to write exactly the query you have outlined, execute it in an `EntityManager`, and it would still participate in all the JPA transactions and so forth.

```
String sql =   "SELECT a.field1, a.field2, a.value as value1, b.value as value2 "
             + "  FROM Fields a, Fields b "
             + " WHERE a.FIELD1 = b.FIELD1 and a.FIELD2 = b.FIELD2 "
             + "   AND a.DISCRIMINATOR = 'A' "
             + "   AND b.DISCRIMINATOR = 'B'";
List<Object[]> result = entityManager.createQuery(sql, Object[].class);

List<FieldValues> result = new ArrayList<FieldValues>();
for (Object[] fieldSet : result) {
    String field1 = (String) fieldSet[0];
    String field2 = (String) fieldSet[1];
    String value1 = (String) fieldSet[2];
    String value2 = (String) fieldSet[3];
    result.add(new FieldValues(field1, field2, value1, value2));
}
```

I believe you can even get Hibernate to map to `FieldValues` for you, but I don't recall how.  It may be as easy as just annotating (or XML-mapping) the `FieldValues` class with the right column names, and then forcing Hibernate to return a `List<FieldValues>` instead from the query.  The downside to this approach is that you cannot make changes to `FieldValue` and have it persisted to the database.

Another approach is to use plain old SQL with [`EntityManager.createNativeQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29).  You have to ensure that you flush the entity manager before doing this; otherwise any pending changes may not have been written to the database and therefore would not be seen by your query.  Again, I believe you can get Hibernate to map to the `FieldValues` class in this case for you.

Comment: Thanks. I figured I could use SQL query, but in that case hibernate mapping would lost its purpose (is there even a use to create the Fields POJO). I begin to think that either my tables or what I trying to achieve are too far from hibernate original purpose.